# HTML text box and button that redirects user to a page of same name as entered text

Tags: html, forms, url, redirect, input

I'm struggling to create an HTML input box that redirects people to a page of the same name.

I'm trying to make a single-line 'input' text box using HTML where a user can enter a domain name, e.g. 'example.com', and upon clicking the [Submit] button they will be redirected to a page based on the text they've entered, e.g. `example.com.html`.

**For example:** If the user typed in `'google.com'` into the input box and clicked [Submit], they'd be redirected to a page of the same name called `'google.com.html'`. I'm setting up an analytics website you see, and this one particular thing has stumped me.

Essentially, each search would require that `'.html'` be added to the end of every search, no spaces are allowed, only web addresses allowed, etc. I'm literally lost at this stage to knowing how to accomplish this.

I sincerely hope I'm not asking too much of this community. What I've managed to do so far is set it so that if the user enters a domain name that I haven't created a page for, they'll be redirected to that URL that doesn't exist and thus redirected again to a customized `404 Not Found` HTTP status page informing them no analytical data was found for that particular website they typed in.

I've been meddling with this for hours and just can't seem to come up with anything.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. You're always more likely to get a response that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried fixing the problem with the following HTML and JS code

```
<input id="test" type=text><button onclick="redirect()">Submit</button>
```

Here is the JS code

```
 function redirect()
  {
    var url=document.getElementById('test').value
    window.location.href=url+".html"
  }
```

Here on Click of the button redirect function will be called which redirect user to the .html page of the input

Comment: Hi Tibin, I just wanted to take the opportunity to thank you for your answer. The code you provided worked perfectly.

Comment: Oh Well and Good. It will be really Great if you could mark the answer as Accepted  ;-)

Happy Coding ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not familiar to this website (I've only just recently joined). I cannot identify any button or link on this page for accepting. Would you be so kind as to direct me to it?

Comment: Hey,It is totally fine :-) 
Just follow the steps mentioned in [https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).This will help you to mark the answer as "Answered"